# How to make sure an object returned will not be modified in Java

Tags: java

In Java you can't return const references to objects as you can in C++. How can I return a reference to an object that will be able to be modified inside a class but not from outside?

Consider this example:

I have class A with an object from class Slave. The object will be returned and used outside of the class A. Here's a code, I hope the comments help understand the problem.

```
public class TestReference
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestReference tr = new TestReference();
        TestReference.A a = tr.new A();

        Slave slave = a.getConstSlave();
        slave.printName();

        a.setSlaveName("New Name");
        slave.printName(); // also changes, this is a reference to the object inside class A

        slave.setName("Fake name"); //this shouldn't be able to happen, we are making modifications outside class A
        slave.printName();
    }

    private class A {
        private Slave slave;
        public A() {
            this.slave = new Slave("A");
        }
        public Slave getConstSlave() {
             // How to make sure this slave will not be modified outside
             // and will keep consistency with this object modifications
             // inside the class A
            return slave;
        }
        public void setSlaveName(String name) {
            slave.setName(name);
        }
    }

    private class Slave {
        private String name;
        public Slave(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void printName() {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using `private` ?

Comment: you want the setName() method to be visible in class A, but not outside of it?

Comment: I want the object to modifiable from inside the class A only but accessible from outside.

Comment: Is putting them in the same package and making the setter protected an option?

Comment: @DeiAndrei I don't think it would since I wouldn't be able to access the slave from outside would I?

Comment: @DeiAndrei It was what you said in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there is no way to do that in java, like you would do it in C++.

What you could do is create an Interface (e.g. ReadOnlySlave) and return that instead of Slave:

```
public interface ReadOnlySlave {
    public void printname();
}

public class Slave : ReadOnlySlave {
   public void printname() { ... }

   public void setName() { .... }
}

public ReadOnlySlave getConstSlave() {
   return slave;
}
```

Then you are able to modify the slave inside your class and the change is visible everywhere, but outside they are not able to change anything.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Not as simple as the C++ way but I think I'll do that. I'll just check the package protected solution from the other answer to decide the the one to accept. Thanks.

Comment: I decided the other answer seems to be a more natural approach. But I also upvoted yours.

Comment: Thanks. The difference is, that my version is more flexible. If Slave and ClassA is in the same class, the protected version works. Imagine if Slave is a Business Object and it is used in different classes, but you still need to give the UI-Layer a readonly version, then the Interface approach is better.

Comment: I think you made your point, if I need to use the slave in multiple classes I may need to put multiple unrelated classes in the same package. That could  ended up being a mess. Maybe this approach is cleaner for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are several option to gain that with their pro' & cons:

1. Remove all set methods.For example remove `setName` method, so can set those fields only from const' or with your builder class if you have one.
2. [Package private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) - meaning you can access those methods from inside the package

   3.Make set methods protected

You can read about the Controlling Access to Members of a Class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should create a package, put classes A and Slave and make the setters from Slave protected? This way the setters will only be able to be used by the class A, Slave and eventual subclasses of Slave. I think this solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: First for package private there no explicit modifier. This is the basic idea but you will need to match is to your use case. Happy it help

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyword for assuring that a returned `Slave` object will not be able to be modified outside class `A`.

However, if you do not want to expose modifiers of `Slave` outside class `A` then do not define a method returning the entire `Slave` object. 
Instead expose only methods that you would like to be accessed in `Slave` from `A`. For example:

```
  private class A {
        private Slave slave;
        public A() {
            this.slave = new Slave("A");
        }
        public Slave getSlaveName() {
            return slave.getName();
        }

        public void setSlaveName(String name) {
            slave.setName(name);
        }

        // And any other getter/setter you would like to expose 
        // but do not return the entire Slave object
    }
```

In other words if `A` is the owner of a `Slave` instance then let `A` "decide" what will be exposed from its `Slave` instance member by defining the proper delegation methods to this `Slave` instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that slave will probably have multiple methods. Will I have to create an additional method on class A for any method that I want to be accessible outside A? This is also a problem if I need to have multiple slave classes inside A.